# Why do I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver when mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar is in the classpath?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver when I type this into the windows command line

```
javac src/*.java -d class -cp lib/*
java DBTest -cp lib/*
```

I have also tried using com.mysql.cj.jdbc without Driver at the end. I add newInstance() to line 11 so it was:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

but there was no change.

I also tried it without Class.forName() since this is deprecated, but I got a java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar is the only file in lib. I have also tried putting it in in the folder where I run DBTest.java. I set the Classpath from the command line using

```
set CLASSPATH = .
```

and by creating the environment variable CLASSPATH through advanced system settings. I then tried compiling and running with and without -cp since it should be checking the current directory for the jar file.

I also tried to run this in eclipse, but eclipse crashed and will no longer open.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees", "root", "root");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employees Limit 10");
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getDouble(3));
            }
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The entire error message is
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments to `java` in the wrong order. Putting arguments **after** the classname will pass those arguments to the main method of your class, it won't set the classpath.

You need to put the arguments **before** the classname. Also `-d class` is not a valid argument for `java`. In short, you need to use:

```
java -cp class:lib/* DBTest
```

Comment: This gives `Error: Could not find or load main class DBTest`. Can you give me any hints as to why that may be? How was it able to find the class and execute up to line 11 before?

Comment: That would indicate that the class is in the current folder and you need to use `-cp .:lib/*` instead, which could mean that the same problem applies to the `javac` commandline as well (I don't regularly use `javac` from the commandline, but probably you need to use `javac -d class -cp lib/* src/*`.